# Get the number of rows of a group by/having

Tags: sql

In a query like:

```
SELECT a, count(b)
FROM table
where condition = …
GROUP by a
having count(b) > 10
```

Is the only way to get only the rows returned, wrapping it in an outside SELECT COUNT FROM (…query..)?

Comment: That is the most reasonable approach.

Comment: Or use analytic function...

Answer (score 1):

As you need two aggregations, one based on the other, yes you need these two steps.

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select a
  from table
  where condition = ...
  group by a
  having count(b) > 10 
) found;
```

Your DBMS might offer a shortcut, though. Oracle allows this for instance:

```
select count(count(b))
from table
where condition = ...
group by a
having count(b) > 10;
```

but this is no longer standard SQL (as far as I am aware of) and thus renders the query less readable for someone not used to this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention which DB you use, but many DBs provide analytic functions, simply try this:

```
SELECT a, count(b), COUNT(*) OVER ()
FROM table
where condition = …
GROUP by a
having count(b) > 10
```

Comment: @Jim: Pavel is right to mention that you didn't name your database system. You should *always* tag your DBMS when asking SQL questions.